# Is there any tool available to automate iOS default (Emai)l app?

Tags: ios, appium, kif, calabash-ios

I have explored couple of tools like Appium,KIF, for these tools we need to own the app (to enable Automation Instrument) to automate. And also tried with .IPA files available on the internet (Gmail email client) on iOS simulator, not got any success yet.

I have requirement to automate iOS default Email app, is there any tool/approach to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yup, Apple has it pretty locked down for apps that are not yours. For that situation, you can try using [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/), which uses a computer vision approach to automation. (Sikuli uses OpenCV under the hood).

If you also want to automate an app on a real device, you can use Sikuli combined with a camera and Tapster, a robot for interacting with a device. (Disclosure: I started the Appium and Tapster projects.)

Comment: Thanks Hugs! Couple of days ago I came to know about Tapster, from one of your team member, Santiago in Se conf 2014 :) Is it possible to automate default app using Appium and Tapster?